# Conditionally add items to a drop-down list

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns in Google Sheets: one is the item `Name` and the other is an indicator of whether it should be included in a drop-down:

[image: columns]

In this example I want the drop-down to include `Item B` and `Item C` and if I were to change the flags in the `Include` column I would want my drop-down either to be expanded or constrained as specified.

How should I create a drop-down which will populate based on the `Include` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Name` is in A1 of Sheet1, then perhaps in C2:

```
=if(B2="Yes",A2,"")
```

copied down to suit and your Validation..., Criteria: List from a range:

```
=Sheet1!C:C
```